# No object in the CompoundRoot has a publicly accessible property named

Tags: java, struts, interceptor

I am trying to send data to `Action` in `Json` format through `Ajax` call. But i am getting following error.

```
1.  No object in the CompoundRoot has a publicly accessible property named 'PersonDetailsAction' (no setter could be found).
2.  Error setting expression 'PersonDetailsAction' with value 'actions.PersonDetailsAction@680e6039'
```

My attempt is following:

Struts.xml

```
<package name="simple" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

    <interceptors>

        <interceptor name="jsonToPOJO" class="interceptors.FromJsonInterceptor" />

        <interceptor-stack name="jsonToPOJOStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonToPOJO"></interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <action name="PersonDetailAction" class="actions.PersonDetailsAction"
        method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="jsonToPOJOStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="dispatcher">/welcome.html</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

home.html

```
function send() {
    var jsonData = {
        "firstName" : "John",
        "lastName" : "Smith",
    }

    $.ajax({
        url : './PersonDetailAction.action',
        type : 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        success : function(data) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;
        },
    });
}
```

PersonDetailsAction.java

```
public class PersonDetailsAction {
    String firstName, lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String execute(){
        return "success";
    }
}
```

FromJsonInterceptor

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actInvc) throws Exception {
    ServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    Gson gsonObject = new Gson();
    PersonDetailsAction pdAction;

    pdAction = gsonObject.fromJson(request.getReader(), PersonDetailsAction.class);
    System.out.println(pdAction.getFirstName());
    System.out.println(pdAction.getLastName());
    ValueStack vs = actInvc.getStack();
    vs.setValue("PersonDetailsAction", pdAction);
    return actInvc.invoke();
}
```

StackTrace:

```
No object in the CompoundRoot has a publicly accessible property named 'PersonDetailsAction' (no setter could be found). - [unknown location]
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.setProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:106)
ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:234)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:183)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:170)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:157)
interceptors.FromJsonInterceptor.intercept(FromJsonInterceptor.java:38)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i corrected the issue.

Earlier what i was doing, setting the `Action` in the value stack. But `Action` are pushed in the stack, and this is the role of the `ActionContext`.

Once the `Action` is pushed into the `ValueStack`, all the property of the `Action` becomes ( atleast it seems to outer world) the property of `ValueStack` and can be accessed directly.

In my case since, `Action` was already pushed, so all i need to do is to `set the property value of the Action`.

Hence following code

```
vs.setValue("PersonDetailsAction", pdAction);
```

should be changed to

```
vs.setValue("firstName", pdAction.getFirstName());
vs.setValue("lastName", pdAction.getLastName());
```